SQLで複数のテーブルからデータを持ってきて、同時に表示する方法が分からない。
usersテーブルにfull_name, full_kana, 1(性別の識別。1は男性、2は女性）,pref_id(都道府県コード）,city_id(市区町村コード）,town_id(町コード）……のようにデータが入っています。
この状態で、usersテーブルのデータを表示していくのですが、その際それぞれprefsテーブル（都道府県コード）、citiesテーブル(市区町村コード）、townsテーブル(町コード）を取得したいです。
usersテーブル
full_name,full_kana,1or2,pref_id,city_id,town_id……

prefsテーブル
code(これがusersテーブルのpref_idと同じ）,name(〇県）

citiesテーブル
code(usersテーブルのcity_idと同じ）,pref_id(usersテーブルのpref_id,prefsテーブルのcodeと同じ）,name(〇市）

townsテーブル
code(usersテーブルのtown_idと同じ）,city_id(usersテーブルのcity_id,citiesテーブルのcodeと同じ）,name(〇町）

このようになっています。
usersテーブルのデータを表示していく中でJOINとかIN?などでテーブルをつなげて表示させようとはしているのですが、うまくいきません。それぞれのテーブルには同じnameという名前が使われていますし、ドットで区別したりしてみましたができませんでした。
表示のスタイルとしては、例えばですが、
田中　太郎、タナカ　タロウ、男性、東京都、渋谷区、代官山町……のように表示したいです。
男性か女性かの部分は、case文でできました。

解説できるほど詳しくありませんが、恐らく「サブクエリ = 副問い合わせ」を使う形になりそうです。 参考 SQLのサブクエリ（副問合せ）とは？

@さよちか 回答の投稿ありがとうございます！　もし可能であれば、どういう書き方にしたら解決したのかを書くように回答を編集いただけますでしょうか。そのようにすることで、後から同じ疑問でこの質問を見に来た方でも問題を解決しやすくすることができます。

一応追記いたしました。おかしいところはあるかもしれません。

サブクエリの使い方を今一度調べなおして、無事できました。
ありがとうございました。
SELECT full_name, full_kana, CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN '男性' ELSE '女性' END AS '性別', postcode, (SELECT name FROM prefs WHERE code = users.pref_id) AS '都道府県', (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE code = users.city_id) AS '市区町村'……
といった形に書き、データを表示できました。
おかしいところはあるかもしれませんが、今のところうまくいっています。
（と言いながら、サブクエリが2桁以上の結果を返します。というエラーに悩まされていますが…(-_-;)）

2桁以上の結果を返します。のエラーも解除できました！
